# MVC4 Doesn't save cookie in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to save a plain text in a cookie in my browser with MVC4, but for some reason it never saves in the browser. I tested in IE, Chrome and FireFox.

I've been trying different solutions on StackOverflow, but none of them have worked for me yet. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong and I hope someone is able to assist me with this problem.

The code I've been using:

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("testKanti"))
{
    // Never makes it here.
}
else
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("testKanti");
    cookie.Value = "testKanti";
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);

    Response.Cookies.Remove("testKanti");
    Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```

I've also tried `Response.Cookies.Add()`, but that didn't work either. Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Use fiddler or similar software to check if the cookies are really sent back to the client.

Comment: Hmm fiddler tells me the following: This response did not set any cookies.

Comment: Where do you set the cookies?

Comment: I set the cookies in a controller action called AddArtikel

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled (or use in-private browsing) in your browser?

Comment: Is there some redirect or similar in your code that might mess with the response?

Comment: @fricke has a good point, can you post the code for the whole action method?

Comment: Sure I can here it is: http://pastebin.com/kxaSpWzZ

Comment: @Mittchel it looks as though your issue might be in the `AddArtikel` method.  You may wish to change `AddArtikel` so that it does whatever it does and then returns execution back to your action method, where you can simply return a `View`.  The cookie usually reaches the user's browser as part of the HTTP response, so if this isn't happening, the user's browser won't receive the cookie.

Comment: For some reason it couldn't be done in the Controller class. When I tried the same code inside a view it worked perfectly. I was only able to retrieve the cookie in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use both strings?

```
Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

I've tried and in my case it works

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("testKanti"))
{
    // We are here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("testKanti");
cookie.Value = "testKanti";
cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

See if you can get the setting of the cookie working first, as removing it from the `Response` object before the response is returned may be causing problems.